# How to get rid of double page breaks in a ReportViewer control-rendered RDLC?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, rdlc

I have a longer report and want to start a Matrix on a new page, so I checked the "Insert Page Break Before" option.
However, whenever a natural page break occurs at this location anyway because the content before this matrix just fills up a page, the ReportViewer control issues this "Insert Page Break Before" regardless, resulting in a whole row of empty pages (my report can be more than 1 page wide). This happens when rendering PDF.

Is there a way to suppress an explicit page break if there already is a natural page break at the same location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that by removing all white space between the Matrix that has the "Page Break Before" set and the element directly above it I eliminated the problem. I suppose that the "Double" page break wasn't really one, but that the empty page actually contained content - the white space that was pushed to a new page.